# Array notation in numpy

Tags: numpy

In Numpy,

What is the difference between

```
import numpy as np
arry = np.array([1,2,3])
```

and

```
import numpy as np
arry = np.array([[1,2,3]])
```

Comment: you have an extra dimension defined in the second one.  First one is a 1d array, second one is 2d.  Verify with `arry.shape`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is 1D array. Second one is 2d array.
Fist one doesn't have a columns. So you can pick an element by

```
arry[0]
```

But the second one you should pick a column, like

```
arry[0, 0]
```

For 2D and higher:

```
arry[row_number, column_number]
```